# BGE: How to make things based on time(definite) instead of frame(relative)

Tags: game-engine

[BGE] How to make things based on time(definite) instead of frame(relative)

Comment: Will you please edit your question, as it is now I'm not sure what you are asking about. What kind of "things" are you dealing with? Is there animation, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The BGE is designed to run with constant frame rate (default 60).

This will work pretty well as long as

- you do not disable the constant frame rate
- the processing time per frame does not exceed the available time per frame